# CRM C# - Custom Workflow Activity - Input Arguments - EntityReference

Tags: c#, crm

I'm Making a custom worflow activity, which is in the process . I have two inputs that are EntityReference . When I test the code appears me an error referenced to these two inputs , as shown in the figure:
[image]
I have a trace at the beginning of the try, but not being shown .
There ir my code:

```
 public class WK_DecorrerObjetivo : CodeActivity
{
    [Input("Alvo")]
    [ReferenceTarget("xpto_alvo")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> alvo { get; set; }

    [Input("Actividade do Objetivo")]
    [ReferenceTarget("xpto_atividadedeobjetivo")]
    public InArgument<EntityReference> atividadeObjetivo { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext Execontext)
    {

        ITracingService _tracing;
        IWorkflowContext context = null;
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = null;
        IOrganizationService service = null;  
        OrganizationServiceContext serviceContext = null;

        try
        {
            #region Get Work Flow Context

            context = Execontext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            serviceFactory = Execontext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
            serviceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

            _tracing = Execontext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            _tracing.Trace("Here");
            EntityReference alvoRef = alvo.Get(Execontext);
            EntityReference atividadeObjetivoRef = atividadeObjetivo.Get(Execontext);
          }
          catch() {}
       }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the workflow process that failed?

Comment: What is the error?